# eclipse pointing to wrong header file

Tags: c, eclipse

I am writing some C code in eclipse. I have some of my own header files and I put them under  project **properties -> GCC C Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths(-l)**. One of the inclded file is **socket.h**. When I try to compile my project compiler still points to default library **(usr/includes/bits/socket.h** and **/usr/includes/sys/socket.h)** But I have my own **socket.h** file which I have included under include paths(-l).

My question is, How can I restrict my compiler to point my socket.h rather than its own socket.h ? One restriction is that I cant change socket.h file name.

Comment: Are you using `"socket.h"` or `<socket.h>` includes?

Comment: What happens if you just use #include"socket.h" ?!

Comment: I thought it could solve the problem. I compiled again but got the same error. I am now going to write a bitbake file to build my project. If there comes any other suggestion I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and fast way to solve this, is to put your **socket.h** in a subfolder and make your include look like this:

```
#include "mysubfolder/socket.h"
```

Add the subfolders parent folder to your include paths and your done.

Comment: I have to add 2 different header files from the same location. **mysubfolder/socket.h and mysubfolder/select.h** this solution works with 1 file but when I add the same path to another header file **mysubfolder/select.h** compiler again points to default socket.h and select.h. any reason why ?

Comment: @shan why wont you rename your socket.h?

Comment: @zubergu because there are many other people in my organisation using this socket.h. I hvnt asked anyone if they are using eclipse or not. I am trying to solve this problem by myself.

Comment: @shan Maybe you should check if one of the header files included above your **#include "mysubfolder/yourheadername"** includes the same header, but without the "mysubfolder" part.

Comment: Without **mysubfolder** includes the default **socket.h and select.h** files. The strange part is if I use **mysubfolder** with one of the include it works fine for that include, but if I use it with both of my header files it doesnt work.